# Comment traduire « long shot »?

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions

Dans les phrases anglaises suivantes :

> That's a bit of a long shot.
>
> It was a long shot, so it was no surprise we didn't get it.

L'expression « [long shot](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wiktionary/en/wiki/long_shot) » représente quelque chose de peu probable, mais pas impossible. J'ai cherché dans un dictionnaire, mais je n'ai pas pu trouver un mot ou une expression similaire à ça.

Comment peut-on exprimer « a long shot » en français ?

Answer (score 10):

Un coup tenté *pour le principe*.
Un travail *sans garantie de résultats*.
« Qui ne tente rien n'a rien. »
Une tentative *désillusionnée*.
Sur un malentendu, ça peut marcher.
On ne sait jamais : ça pourrait quand même marcher.

Answer (score 10):

Je traduirais par *osé* dans ton deuxième exemple

> C'était un peu osé, je ne suis pas étonné qu'on ne l'ait pas eu.

Pour ton premier exemple, j'utilise souvent *miraculeux*

> Ce serait un peu miraculeux.

Answer (score 8):

Dans certains contextes, si il n'y a pas d'alternatives viables, *tentative désespérée* peut convenir.

Answer (score 6):

> - C'est un coup risqué
> - C'était un coup risqué, on n'est pas surpris de l'avoir raté

*Long shot :* tentative risquée (notion d'exécution difficile).

***Edit***

Si l'on considère que tir est long, que la cible est éloignée, que le contexte peut varier selon le locuteur et l'humeur du scribe, on peut essayer les transpositions pour le sujet, le but et le résultat:

> - À cette distance, la cible paraît toute petite... la rater n'est pas un drame.
> - C'était un peu loin pour l'avoir du premier coup, il n'y a faute.
> - L'avoir eu du premier coup eut été un miracle.
> - Flèche trop courte, c'est pas Ulysse qui tenait l'arc !
> - Faudrait avoir l'œil aquilin pour réussir à voir précisément si loin sans se tromper.

Pour les ambitions sociales, plus littéraire ou proverbiale :

> - Comme [*Gervaise*](http://www.linternaute.com/livre/magazine/1004963-15-personnages-de-la-litterature-qui-nous-agacent/1004981-gervaise), elle a visé trop haut.
> - Du [*mat de cocagne*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A2t_de_cocagne) les faibles ne voient jamais le dessus.
> - À tentative risquée, succès non assuré.

Answer (score 4):

Je ne vois pas d'expression adéquate; faute de mieux, je suggérerais *[rocambolesque](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rocambolesque)*, voire *[abracadabrant](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/abracadabrant)*, *[alambiqué](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/alambiqu%C3%A9/adjectif)* ou [tarabiscoté](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tarabiscot%C3%E2).

Pour le deuxième, puisque ça n'a pas marché, on peut aussi jouer les défaitistes :

> C'était couru d'avance, pas étonnant qu'on ne l'aie pas eu.

Comment: Le problème avec les solutions du type _rocambolesque, abracadabrant, alambiqué ou tarabiscoté_ c'est que cela introduit une connotation de "compliqué" qui n'est pas présente dans l'expression _long shot_ en Anglais. _Tentative désespérée_ ou _osé_ sont plus proches.

Answer (score 2):

"Ce n'est pas gagné d'avance" is quite popular as well.

> That's a bit of a long shot.
>
> *Ce n'est pas gagné d'avance.*

.

> It was a long shot, so it was no surprise we didn't get it.
>
> *Ce n'était pas gagné d'avance donc ce n'est pas surprenant que nous ne l'ayions pas eu.*

Answer (score 1):

**Tordu*, **Tiré par les cheveux**, ou encore **capillotracté** ? =)

Answer (score 1):

Le [*long shot*](http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/long%20shot), c'est comme on l'a résumé en question l' « attempt or effort that is not likely to be successful » (Merriam Learners) ; la tentative ou l'effort ayant peu de chances d'être couronné de succès, dont la réalisation est peu probable. [*Larousse en ligne*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/long_shot/592877) suggère simplement :

> *It's a bit of a long shot.* Il y a peu de chances pour que cela réussisse.

C'est en effet ce que signifie l'emploi au [figuré](https://www.etymonline.com/word/long%20shot) pour *something [unlikely](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/unlikely/621398)*.

Answer (score -3):

Peut-être que ça coïncide avec « Tir lointain » ou « prise (de photo) lointaine ».

Comment: Pas vraiment, non.