# « C'est un long shot » et « il y a peu de chances pour que » etc. : comparaison en contexte ?

Tags: oral, syntaxe, auxiliaires, emprunts, attributs

Dans la version française du dialogue d'une mini-série canadienne, on emprunte directement le substantif [*long shot*](http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/long%20shot) (dont on discute dans une [autre question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/1417)) qu'on emploie dans une construction [attributive](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%AAtre) servant peut-être à ramener l'objet comme sujet :

> Sarah : [...] Y'en a plus de billets, ce soir c'est LE soir, t'as
>   tout' gâché.
>   Karen : Reste polie hein...
>  Ross : [Wo](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/wo#Fran%C3%A7ais), Bob, y a pas quelqu'un
>   qu'tu peux appeler, dans ce milieu-là ?
>  Bob : J'vas essayer
>   que(l)que chose, **c'tun long shot** mais... on va voir [prend son
>   mobile]
>  Wendy/Karen : Tu connais surement quelqu'un, comment i(l)
>   s'appelle... le p'tit gros avec une... les cheveux... Jerrold ? [...].
>  Ross :
>   S'cusez, faut q'j'prenne ça... [sort son mobile, répond] Ouais ?
>  Bob :
>   Ah, hi, c'est Bob Durelle...
>  Ross : Qui ?
>  Bob : C'est moi...
>   écoute, notre chère ange adorée a besoin de billets pour le show des
>   *Front Street Boys* à soir, penses-tu tu peux m'aider ?
>  Ross : Vite
>   de même là ? (At)tends un peu, m'(en v)as checker ça. Hmm... ben
>   (re)garde donc ça... [sort de sa poche...] Quatre tickets pis une backstage pass pour après
>   le show...
>  [tous sont en liesse].
>
> [ [*Le dernier chapitre*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Dernier_Chapitre), Richard Roy (Luc Dionne), 2002, ep. 1,
>   24:56. ]

Si on remanie le tour avec l'auxiliaire [*avoir*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/avoir) (*il y a peu de chances pour que cela réussisse*, [Larousse en ligne](http://il%20y%20a%20peu%20de%20chances%20pour%20que%20cela%20r%C3%A9ussisse) : *(il) y a peu d'chances qu'ça marche*, disons) on a  recours à un morphème de présentation (*il y a*), plutôt qu'à l'emploi plus personnel avec le pronom *je/nous*.

---

Peut-on analyser et comparer les deux fonctions (de détermination du nom, ce *quelque chose* que l'on va essayer ; ou d'un autre genre), la valeur d'attribut et celle de présentation, leur nuance, et leur utilité en contexte :

- La tournure avec l'emprunt à l'anglais permet-elle un emploi plus
  usuel de la même fonction syntaxique ?
- La tournure avec *il y a* s'avère-t-elle un détour stylistique pour
  éviter une formulation débutant par l'article indéfini *un(e)*
  (quelle serait-elle, *chance aidant* ?) ou simplement une manière de
  ramener l'objet au premier plan, s'agit-il d'un emploi comme
  *morphème de présentation* ?

Comment: Pourquoi Bob ne sort pas son mobile puis n'ajoute pas simplement « ça risque de ne pas marcher ». Évidemment il y a une mise en scène ici, et la formulation est plus longue et avec une syntaxe différente. La comparaison est asymétrique mais on s'intéresse aussi à la différence entre l'emploi des deux auxiliaires/constructions servant à réaliser la fonction plus ou moins discrète de détermination/qualification ; l’emprunt est-il déterminant ici ; dans la question liée de traduction on a à première vue des suggestions avec l'aux. _être_ suivi d'un adjectif/participe., mais pas d'un nom... Merc !

Answer (score 3):

La tournure avec emprunt à l'anglais permet en effet de garder la structure de la phrase à l'identique.

L'emploi de "il y a" n'est pas une tournure stylistique pour éviter une répétition, il fait simplement partie de l'expression "il y a peu de chances" (= c'est improbable).

Si on voulait réutiliser le même genre de tournure que l'anglais sans emprunter *long shot*, on pourrait aussi dire

> Je vais essayer quelque chose, c'est un coup désespéré mais...
>
> Je vais essayer quelque chose, c'est sans grand espoir, mais...
>
> Je vais essayer quelque chose,  sans trop y croire, mais...

Answer (score 2):

> Bob : J’vas essayer que(l)que chose, **c’[es]t un long shot** mais... on va voir [prend son mobile]

La recomposition avec l’auxiliaire *avoir* ne force pas le côté représentatif de la chose sans participation du sujet. En suivant la proposition de Larousse, on pourrait penser à quelque chose comme :

> Bob : J’vas essayer que(l)que chose, **il y a peu de chance de réussite** mais... on va voir [prend son mobile]

Je reconnais que ce n’est guère concis.

On repensant un peu la chose, on pourrait parvenir à un résultat plus court et plus naturel dans un contexte québécois, sans pour autant faire disparaître ce fameux *je* de la phrase :

> Bob : J’vas essayer que(l)que chose, **probablement un pétard mouillé** mais... on va voir [prend son mobile]

Ou même, très près de la proposition alternative originale :

> Bob : J’vas essayer que(l)que chose, **peu de chance de réussite** mais... on va voir [prend son mobile]

Si l’on veut conserver l’idée de [la distance de la cible](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/long_shot), on pourrait imaginer une expression imagée qui, sans être attestée, pourrait <strike>aisément</strike> peut-être se comprendre

> Bob : J’vas essayer que(l)que chose, **la cible est loin** mais... on va voir [prend son mobile]

Si l’on veut demeurer dans le plus traditionnel, on pourrait proposer :

> Bob : J’vas essayer que(l)que chose. **Il y a loin de la coupe aux lèvres** mais... on va voir [prend son mobile]

Et enfin, je suppose que le recours à un nom sans adverbe pourrait rendre l’affirmation plus *punchée*... Pourrait-on alors considérer <sub>*(??? peut-être n’est-ce pas idéal, selon un commentaire laissé ci-dessous...)*</sub> :

> <sub>Bob : J’vas essayer que(l)que chose, **c’[es]t un tir à longue portée** mais... on va voir [prend son mobile]</sub>

Une autre possibilité de conserver la structure avec un nom, ultimement peut-être ma préférée de toutes, pourrait être de regarder ailleurs que dans le tir à la cible et parler du **facteur chance**.

Il présente quelques particularités, auxquelles on pourra attribuer ou non d’importance :

- On maintient l’incertitude mesurée d’un tir à longue portée, dont le résultat est un délicat dosage de connaissances, d’habileté et de hasard <sub>*(la part du hasard m’y semble moins grande qu’avec* pétard mouillé *ou* coup désespéré, *proposés ici et ailleurs)*</sub> ;
- Le terme est communément rencontré dans la langue usuelle (au moins au Québec...);
- Il n’est par contre en aucune manière un synonyme du *longshot* original, même s’il traduit assez bien le rapport de l’interlocuteur avec les possibilités de succès de l’exercice.

Ça pourrait donner quelque chose comme :

> Bob : J’vas essayer que(l)que chose, **avec le facteur chance**... ça pourrait marcher [prend son mobile]

---

Il va de soi que la traduction de l’audio-visuel est soumise à d’autres types de contraintes que la simple traduction de l’écrit. Mes propositions tiennent peu compte de la synchronisation du mouvement des lèvres, pour la simple raison que je suis plus lecteur que public de théâtre ou de télévision. Ça laisse donc la place libre pour ceux qui s’y connaîtront plus que moi en ces matières, ce qui pourrait s’avérer pertinent en ce cas particulier...

Comment: Personnellement je n'aurais pas compris "la cible est loin" ou "c'est un tir à longue portée" avec ce sens-là.

Answer (score 1):

"It's a long  shot" if informal, I would  translate: 
C'est pas gagné! Or
C'est pas gagné d'avance 
You can add: "c'est vraiment pas gagné d'avance": we use "antiphrase" a lot in French: "c'est pas gagné d'avance" = it's not won/in the bag ,( or: it is not a given), actually means more than just that: you think it WILL fail, but cannot say for sure. 
Another way,- like the other answer above says- is to say: ça a (très) peu de chances de réussir. 
Or : ça a très peu de chance de marcher (marcher as in work)..
And in spoken language, French people will often conclude that thought with "...mais bon." As to say, "just saying" or "ok lets try that anyway".

For the second sentence, "it was a long shot, so, we weren't surprised"... 
I would say: "c'était (plus ou moins) perdu d'avance, alors on n'est pas vraiment surpris."

Funnily enough, "long shot" (= long feu, feu being "fire" like when firing a pistol) is used in a different expression in French: "ce project ne va pas faire long feu" : that project won't last long/will fail soon.